# Javascript - text rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

www.davidscotthealthcaremarketing.com
On the home page, there is an animation with javascript that is also in an iframe - I did not create this file but I am investigating how to fix it. I need a second opinion on how to fix it!

The problem is that the text in the animation looks wrong on Chrome & IE, but looks correct on Firefox and Safari. I am not so familiar with javascript so I am trying to determine if this problem is a browser issue, or if it can be fixed within the code.

From what I can see in the code the correct font is included: Copperplate Gothic Bold. Please see my screenshot at bottom. I'm guessing it is just the browsers, but I want to seek some help in case there was anything that can be done to the code to fix this issue. Willing to pay for your time as well. Thanks!

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sDlA.jpg)

Comment: what versions of chrome and IE? more than likely a browser support issue with that specific font

Answer (score -1):

If you include the css code, we can give you better adives (and I'll edit my answer).

I guess the **custom font** added doesn't have all the font types needed for cross-browser compatibility like **.eot, ttf , wof.**

- .eot   /* IE */
- .woff2 /* Super Modern Browsers */
- .woff  /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
- .ttf   /* Safari, Android, iOS */
- .svg   /* Legacy iOS */

Comment: Here is the CSS I found:text[Attributes Style] {
    font-family: 'Copperplate Gothic Bold:0';
    font-size: 600px;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

Comment: I guess it threw me off because of the javascript, but I will make sure the font choice has what is needed for browser support. Thanks!